# Sharepoint Net Webclient retrieving via powershell output always HTML

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, webclient

I have a script I'm working on to deploy BGInfo to a large list of devices, they are mainly POS terminals - relevant and will come up later.

My issue is I have a repository of around 6 files I need to push out to these devices, there is a large variance in Powershell version numbers with the lowest being 2.0 meaning so I can't use invoke-webrequest to download the files from SharePoint, I have to use WebClient.DownloadFile for this action, the issue with my clearly basic script seems to be outputting the files as nearly identical HTML files and not my files that I get from the URL if I place it directly in a browser.

I've tried the same script within Google Drive direct URL also and it does work for a period but will eventually lose token Auth. So there's clearly some kind of masking happening with the Sharepoint URLs that I'm not understanding.

Sample script & crux of the issue(

```
$Zealpath = "C:\ProgramData\Zeal"
If(!(test-path $Zealpath))
{
      New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $Zealpath
}

If(!(test-path $BGIpath))
{
      New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $BGIpath
}

$BGIurl = "https://zealconsultants.sharepoint.com/:u:/s/Software/EfoalXiCqhtFgAvuCbtY9RsB2WPSTFwsJ2gtvV2bg0rQww?e=yvZhIW&download=1"
$BGIoutput = "C:\ProgramData\Zeal\BGInfo\bginfo.exe"

$wc = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.Headers.Add("User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36")
$wc.DownloadFile($BGIurl, $BGIoutput)        #deploy to .exe
```

So yeah, direct URL downloads the BGInfo.exe, and running this via powershell will output an HTML file.

Any help kindly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is the URL. Doesn't seem to pointing to the file.

Also make sure the entire path is created. If the BGInfo folder doesn't exist, the download function will fail.

Try this:

```
$Zealpath = "C:\ProgramData\Zeal\BGInfo"
If(-not (test-path $Zealpath -PathType Container))
{
      New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $Zealpath
}

$BGIurl = "https://zealconsultants.sharepoint.com/sites/Software/Shared%20Documents/Atera%20Scripted%20Deployments/BGInfo/Bginfo.exe"
$BGIoutput = "C:\ProgramData\Zeal\BGInfo\bginfo.exe"

$wc = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.Headers.Add("User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36")
$wc.DownloadFile($BGIurl, $BGIoutput)
```

Comment: Yeah still the same issue, still just a copy of the HTML linking to the website but not the actual file itself.

Yeah sorry about the directory creation this isn't the entire script and I had missed the creation of the directory when posting here.

Comment: No, the code I posted actually works. I tested it on my laptop and it creates the path and downloads the file. The issue is elsewhere.

Comment: It downloads a file, yes, but it's not the .exe, it's an HTML file of the webpage. The file should be around 3MB, the file it retrieves is 139KB, if opened with notepad you'll see.

I've tested this on the POS terminals, and a couple of Windows 10 machines the output is always the same.

Directly inputting the URL into a browser pulls the file correctly running it in PowerShell doesn't.

Comment: The website it downloads, is a redirect. So again. The issue is the URL. Powershell doesn't get redirected but the browser does. That is why it works on browsers and not Powershell.

Comment: Thanks for your time on it anyway.